# How to cast JSON text field to UUID in PostgreSQL plpgsql function

Tags: json, casting, plpgsql, uuid

I have the following function that I use in a RPC (Remote Procedural Call) within which I attempt to access a JSON object's optional text field and cast it to a UUID:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_wcomponent (item wcomponents)
returns wcomponents
language plpgsql
security definer
SET search_path = public
as $$
DECLARE
  existing wcomponents%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN

  UPDATE wcomponents
  SET
    modified_at = now(),
    title = item.json::json->'title',
    type = item.json::json->'type',
    -- Following line errors
    attribute_id = (item.json::json->'attribute_wcomponent_id')::text::uuid,
    json = item.json
  WHERE id = item.id AND modified_at = item.modified_at;

  -- Get the latest value
  SELECT * INTO existing FROM wcomponents WHERE id = item.id;

  return existing;
END;
$$;
```

However it errors on casting the text to uuid with the error:

`invalid input syntax for type uuid: ""310edbfb-0af1-411b-9275-3fc87948c3a5""`

Where I post it a JSON object of the following structure:

```json
{
    "item": {
        "base_id": 18,
        "id": "27e46ec1-3d9a-412d-9807-8e08e515988d",
        "json": {
            "id": "27e46ec1-3d9a-412d-9807-8e08e515988d",
            "title": "",
            "type": "state_value",
            "attribute_wcomponent_id": "310edbfb-0af1-411b-9275-3fc87948c3a5"
        },
        "modified_at": "2022-04-23T22:11:13.533Z"
    }
}
```

`attribute_wcomponent_id` is optional, so this works fine when its `undefined` as it will just be absent.

How do I successfully cast it from a json text attribute to uuid?  It seems the text string is quoted as `"310edbfb-0af1-411b-9275-3fc87948c3a5"` rather than just `310edbfb-0af1-411b-9275-3fc87948c3a5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [`->>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html) operator to return your `attribute_wcomponent_id` value as `text`, rather than `json`. Then the conversion to type `text` prior to `uuid` is not necessary, and you no longer have the double quoting issue that you are seeing.

```sql
attribute_id = (item.json::json->>'attribute_wcomponent_id')::uuid
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b820cec102075723d3876f07648b88ce)